# convert screenshot taken from protractor to pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, selenium, protractor

I have a small code written using protractor to take screenshot. But I want to save that screenshot as a pdf. Below is my code.

```
await browser.get(url);
const img = await browser.takeScreenshot();
const buf = Buffer.from(img, 'base64');
writeFile("example.pdf",buf,(err)=>{
    if (err)
          console.log(err);
     else {
          console.log("File written successfully\n");
          console.log("The written has the following contents:");
          console.log(readFileSync("example.pdf", "utf8"));
       }
     });
```

but the file seems corrupted. I'm getting below error when I opened the file.
[image]

So how can I convert the image I'm getting from this line `const img = await browser.takeScreenshot();` to pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly save image as pdf file. You need to use a conversion too like [jspdf](http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html). Here is sample code:

```
const { jsPDF } = require("jspdf")
const fs = require("fs")
const doc = new jsPDF();
// await browser.get(url);
// const image = await browser.takeScreenshot();

const image = fs.readFileSync("./image.jpg")
const buf = Buffer.from(image, 'base64');

doc.addImage(buf, "jpg", 5, 5)
doc.save("result.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm getting error on this line --> doc.addImage(buf, "jpg", 5, 5)

it says --> No overload expects 4 arguments, but overloads do exist that expect either 1 or 8 arguments.ts(2575)

Comment: My example is written in nodejs environment. Are you in browser environment?